# Android TableRow stretch vertically to fill screen

Tags: android

I'm trying to create a phone dialer view, using a TableLayout to create the 12 buttons in a 3x4 grid.  I would like the rows to stretch vertically to use up all available space equally, but it appears fill_parent doesn't work on TableRows.

I would like not to have to use setMinimumHeight - is there a way to do this properly in the layout?

Thanks very much,

Ed

Answer (score 63, accepted):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>
<TableLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:stretchColumns="*"
    >
    <TableRow 
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center">
        <Button android:text="Button" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
        <Button android:text="Button" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
        <Button android:text="Button" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow 
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center">
        <Button android:text="Button" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
        <Button android:text="Button" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
        <Button android:text="Button" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow 
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center">
        <Button android:text="Button" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
        <Button android:text="Button" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
        <Button android:text="Button" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow 
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center">
        <Button android:text="Button" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
        <Button android:text="Button" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
        <Button android:text="Button" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: I was going to post a solution with the buttons in 2 nested Linearlayouts, but seems your solutions works fine too, and is also using a TableLayout, as the OP asked. :)

Comment: Cool, but how to do it in java code? I try to get similar result with number of rows and columns known only at runtime, but get `java.lang.ArithmeticException: divide by zero` in `android.widget.TableLayout.mutateColumnsWidth(TableLayout.java:579)`. Can't even believe that Android layout system is really so much retarded.

Comment: Thanks , it was awesome using android:stretchColumns="*"

Comment: This is a good answer, the only thing I noticed is that `LinearLayout` is redundant.

Comment: Thanks a ton for this answer. Could you explain whether LinearLayout is actually needed? Thanks!

Comment: This is one of the simplest and cleanest grids I've seen. Cheers.

Comment: I need to stretch only one column, and then, I do android:stretchColumns="1" (zero-based column count)

Comment: android:layout_weight="1" did it ;)