# make it the GridLayout way in android

Tags: java, android, grid-layout

Hello I have this Screen

[image]

that i made by this code .

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.example.test.project"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <Button
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                app:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
                android:text="1" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                app:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
                android:text="2" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                app:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
                android:text="3" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <Button
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                app:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
                android:text="4" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                app:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
                android:text="5" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                app:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
                android:text="6" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <Button
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                app:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
                android:text="7" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                app:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
                android:text="8" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                app:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
                android:text="9" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <Button
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                app:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
                android:text="10" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                app:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
                android:text="11" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                app:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
                android:text="12" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Is there a way to do it with `GridLayout` , i tried to have GridLayout but it works only with 2 buttons in a row ,but with 3 it doesnot work , i used the code in the [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10033481/838793) answer?

Comment: GridLayout will work with 3 buttons in a row if you specify android:columnCount="3"

Comment: You can't, but try with a Table Layout, is pretty similar. [Link.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5538366/android-tablerow-stretch-vertically-to-fill-screen)

Answer (score 0):

You wont like my answer, but put plainly, you can't. GridLayout doesn't support any type of layout "weighting" per say. For text, you can usually use the app:layout_gravity options, but for items like buttons, that won't work.

Your best bet is to just use linear layouts inside of the GridLayout. Doesn't really improve much from what you already have, but at least you can get rid of the first linear layout you have. All you would need is GridLayout at top, then 1 linear layout for each row of buttons. That would increase performance.

http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/11/new-layout-widgets-space-and-gridlayout.html

The "Emulating Features from other Layouts" section hints at how using the LinearLayout in the GridLayout for this scenario is the better option.

Answer (score -1):

You have to change GridLayout android:rowCount="3". try this [link](http://blog.stylingandroid.com/archives/669) and [this](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-user-interface-design-creating-a-numeric-keypad-with-gridlayout/)

```
<GridLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:columnCount="3"
    android:rowCount="3" >

    <TextView
        android:text="1,1" />

    <TextView
        android:text="1,2" />

    <TextView
        android:text="1,3" />


    <TextView
        android:text="2,1" />

    <TextView
        android:text="2,2" />

    <TextView
        android:text="2,3" />

    <TextView
        android:text="3,1" />

    <TextView
        android:text="3,2" />

    <TextView
        android:text="3,3" />


</GridLayout>
```

Edit:
Read this [link](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/11/new-layout-widgets-space-and-gridlayout.html), [link](http://android-meda.blogspot.com/2012/02/tutorial-using-layouts-in-your-android.html)

Comment: it will make every 3 textview in a row but they will not fill the entire width of parent !!!!

Comment: @user4o01 check this link may be it will help.. http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-gridview-layout-tutorial/

Comment: my friend , it won't its about GridView not GridLayout